# Uncaught FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data, Data must be an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently trying to make a questionnaire with users rating an image. I want to push the value the user rated the image alongside which image they have rated to a database. I am currently printing this to the console log, but having trouble sending it to the database. It says that the data of the radio button is not an object. This is my first time using firebase and have little experience of JS.

```js
function validate() {
    var radio = document.getElementsByName("answer");
    var checked = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
        if (radio[i].checked) {
            checked = true;
            break;
        } else {
            checked = false;
        }
    }
    if (checked) {
        for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++)
        {
            if (radio[i].checked)
            {
                selected = (radio[i].value)
                window.sessionStorage.setItem("selected", JSON.stringify(selected));
                console.log(selected)
                changeImage();
            }
        } 
        
    } else {
        alert("You must select an answer!")
    }
} 

 
var currentImage = 0;
var imageArray = ["/Users/rate/images/images/practice/sun1.jpg", "/Users/rate/images/images/practice/sun2.jpg", "/Users/rate/images/images/practice/sun3.jpg", "/Users/rate/images/images/practice/sun4.jpg"]
function changeImage(){
    if (currentImage >= imageArray.length - 1) {
        writeToDB();
      } else {
        currentImage += 1;
      }
    document.getElementById("mainImage").src = imageArray[currentImage]
    img = imageArray[currentImage].slice(-8)
    console.log(img)
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("selected", JSON.stringify(img));
}



function writeToDB() {

    var selected = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("selected"));

    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "***",
        authDomain: "**",
        databaseURL: "**",
        projectId: "**",
        storageBucket: "**",
        messagingSenderId: "**",
        appId: "**",
        measurementId: "**"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    var db = firebase.firestore();
    db.collection("selected").doc().set(selected)
        .then(function () {
            console.log("Document successfully written!");
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
        });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title> App Icons </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Users/rate/css/mainstyle.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Users/rate/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
</head>



<body class="body">
    <div>
        <div>
            <hr>
            <div class=topbar>
                <h1> Do you find this App Icon aesthically pleasing</h1>
            </div>
            <hr>

            <div class=image> 
            <img src="/Users/rate/images/images/practice/sun1.jpg" id="mainImage"/>
            </div>
            <hr>

            <div class=answer> 
            <div id=answer>
                <label> Strongly Agree </label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="1" required><span>1</span></label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="2" required><span>2</span></label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="3" required><span>3</span></label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="4" required><span>4</span></label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="5" required><span>5</span></label>
                <label> Strongly disagree</label>
                <hr>
            </div>



            </div>
            
            <div class=complete> 
                <input type="button" onclick="validate()" value="I am complete">
            </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You're trying to write the image src string to the database, without idenfitying any sort of key. You're not, in fact, trying to update the collection with an actual doc. 
In your particular case, it might make sense to have a doc with a key called `images`, perhaps, and have that key contain a true array. Then, in the update, you read the array and `[...arr, selected]` to add it to that array.

Comment: yes I am happy to write the image src string to the database so that i can identify the rate for that image! how would i do what you are suggesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by added the image name and rated value to a dictionary

Answer (score 2):

So the answer is a bit more involved, given that you want to have more data than you're actually telling the database. The data structure for each document might be more like this:

```
{
  url: /* string containing image's url */,
  rating: [4, 2, 5, 0] /* array containing ratings given for this image
}
```

And *each image* should be represented in much the same way - so if you had a collection called `images`, then you might have something like this:

```js
const dbRef = firebase.firestore();
const imagesRef = dbRef.collection('images');

const oneImage = imagesRef.doc('JdBPHMYWfNMMlMpfsjv5');
oneImage.get().then(function(doc){
  console.log( doc.data() )
  // that might return 
  {
    'url': '/img/sun002.jpg',
    'rating': [5,2,3,2,0,5]
  }

  /***
   * but! In your case, you'd likely want to create the HTML fragment
   * you'll be injecting for this particular image:
   ***/
  // so let's pull all the stuff out of the database, and create an object
  //  that includes the image's id.
  const image = {id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }

  // Using that, we can create an HTML fragment that generates the radio buttons
  const imageEl = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(`<div class='img-container'>
  <img src='${image.url}'>
  <fieldset class='image-rating'>Rate this image: 
    <label>0 <input type='radio' name='rating' data-uid='${image.id}' value=0 /></label>
    <label>1 <input type='radio' name='rating' data-uid='${image.id}' value=1 /></label>
    <label>2 <input type='radio' name='rating' data-uid='${image.id}' value=2 /></label>
    <label>3 <input type='radio' name='rating' data-uid='${image.id}' value=3 /></label>
    <label>4 <input type='radio' name='rating' data-uid='${image.id}' value=4 /></label>
    <label>5 <input type='radio' name='rating' data-uid='${image.id}' value=5 /></label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
'`)

// Let's add a listener for the click on the wrapper for all these radios
imageEl.querySelector('.image-rating').addEventListener('click', handleRatingClick)

// And finally, let's add this image block to the page!
document.querySelector("#images-content-pane").appendChild(imageEl)

})
```

Note that each image is its own `doc` in the collection, but that it can contain whatever properties you might like. You might add a `caption` property, or whatever might be useful to you.

But there are a few things to note:

1. I'm programmatically creating each image's container, and dynamically adding the listener to each one's fieldset.
2. I'm adding a `data-uid` attribute to each radiobutton. We need that later, so we know *which* image doc we're updating!

Then, later on, when you are adding a rating for *this* image, you would simply reference this particular image and add the chosen rating to the array:

```js
// In my case, I had a fieldset wrap all my radio buttons, and a click was handled there:
const handleRatingClick = (event) =>{
  // First, let's get the clicked el:
  const ratingBtn = event.target;
  const imageId = ratingBtn.dataset.uid;
  const rating = ratingBtn.value;


  // And here I update the array in the rating property, by adding the given value
  imagesRef.doc(imageId).update({
    rating: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(Number(rating))
  })

}
```

Note that this isn't the only way, or even the right way. The point being, you need to consider each image as a doc in the database, and you need to provide firestore with an object when you either create it, or update it.

You *could* do as you're doing, and work with the image in localStorage/sessionStorage, but even then, the value in sessionStorage would need to be an object, containing

```js
{
  url,
  answer
}
```

And doing `.set()` with that will simply overwrite the value of answer each time, rather than storing them over time. Also, for yours to work, you'd need to store a doc.id somewhere.

This is a very long-winded way of saying "Yes, this is very do-able, but it's a pretty darn advanced topic." I *do* have a repl of this working: https://repl.it/@TobiasParent/Firestore-image-doc

Comment: thank you for all of this! i ended up solving the issue, by storing the image name and the rated value within a dictionary and passed it to the firebase